# Program not use the same cpu core number between two OS

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, c, cpu-usage, yocto

I have a program in C who use SDL2.

When I run my program on my Raspberry with Raspbian OS, it uses all core (I can see this with `htop`).

When I run the same program on the same Raspberry but with a custom OS (build with Yocto), it uses only one core. This has the effect of performance drop because the core used is at 100%.

Do you have an idea about my problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Compare the build configuration for the two kernels. Investigate the differences

Comment: Thanks for comment, in kernel configuration I have seen "multicore sheduler", I think that is this option that I need to enable.

Comment: Many possible sources … Do you see all cores under `/sys/devices/system/cpu` at all? What `defconfig` did you use? Do you need to enable SMP support in the `EXTRA_OECONF` of your `libsdl2` recipe?